# About PHP and gz-compression

Tags: php, compression, gzip

I was looking for gz-compression in PHP and I found this piece of code:

```
<?php
function print_gzipped_output()
{
    $HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"];
    if( headers_sent() )
        $encoding = false;
    else if( strpos($HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING, 'x-gzip') !== false )
        $encoding = 'x-gzip';
    else if( strpos($HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING,'gzip') !== false )
        $encoding = 'gzip';
    else
        $encoding = false;

   if( $encoding ) {
        $contents = ob_get_clean();
        $_temp1 = strlen($contents);
        if ($_temp1 < 2048)    // no need to waste resources in compressing very little data
            print($contents);
        else
        {
            header('Content-Encoding: '.$encoding);
            print("\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00");
            $contents = gzcompress($contents, 9);
            $contents = substr($contents, 0, $_temp1);
            print($contents);
        }
    }
    else
        ob_end_flush();
}
?>
```

My question is simple: what does the line

```
print("\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00");
```

actually means?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just a side note that compression is really much better handled by your web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the header for gzip-format files. You can view more details [here](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html#header-trailer).

The first two bytes identify the file as gzipped. The following `8` specifies the use of the `DEFLATE` compression method. The final four zero bytes are for fields which aren't needed.